# Issue writing file with powershell script using Progress Preference

Tags: powershell

I have the following code...

```
$htmlexport = @"
powershell -Command "$progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest https://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/hrrr/prod/hrrr.$m2/conus/hrrr.t$m21z.wrfsfcf00.grib2 -OutFile C:\OpenGrADS-2.2\data\hrrr\hrrr000.grb2"
exit
"@
$htmlexport | Out-File C:\OpenGrADS-2.2\001-HRRR\HRRR-DOWNLOADGRIBFILES.bat -Encoding UTF8
```

When the file is written, $progressPreference gets changed to Continue, so it looks like this...

```
powershell -Command "Continue = 'silentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest
```

How can I get it to write the file without changing "progresspreference" to "continue"?

Comment: escape it using a back tick: `\`$ProgressPreference `. Or use single quotes. I have no clue how to put a back tick in a code block lol - edit - fixed it!

Comment: Double quotes will allow the variable expansion, use `@'...'@` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am fairly new to this and I had now idea I could do that.  It worked like a charm.

Comment: @santiago, i used a backslash instead lol